# How does "extern C++" work?

Tags: c++, templates, extern

I jumped into `winnt.h` and I found out the code as following:

```
extern "C++" // templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
template <typename T, size_t N>
char (*RtlpNumberOf( UNALIGNED T (&)[N] ))[N];
```

I'd like to ask questions as following:

1. how does `extern "C++"` work?
2. is this portable among GCC, and Clang?
3. can all templates be exported with this syntax?

---

With question 3, I mean that can I separate declearation and definition of the templates, and then generate a dynamic link for the template without actually give the implementation by using this trick?

Comment: Good question! Very limited information about this can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d.aspx

Comment: @NemanjaBoric I've tried MSDN, but found nothing about `extern "C++"` there.

Comment: Presumably this is inside a region of `extern "C"`. In C++03 template instantiations always had extern linkage. I'm not sure how in C++11 this is done for instantiation on local types, but presumably in about the same way as for things in an anonymous namespace. So apparently the above does nothing except to *cancel* the implicit `extern "C"` of the region this declaration is placed in.

Comment: It seems that C++ is a default linkage used in C++:

From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, `extern "C++"` won't work in C, of course (though some compilers might support it as an extension). So it only makes sense to use it in C++.

That's because in the case of multiple nested extern linkage specifiers, the innermost one takes effect. So if you have a header file surrounded with `extern "C"`, you can use `extern "C++"` to temporarily break out of it and declare something with C++ linkage.

It makes the most sense when you want to provide a generally C interface for a C++ library, but you also want to provide C++ helper bits for people actually using it in C++. So you'd put `#ifdef __cplusplus \ extern "C" { \ #endif` around the header as a whole, and then you ifdef-in those bits with `extern "C++"` to revert to C++ linkage.

Comment: The Win32 API, which is where winnt.h comes from, is a C-based API.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Exactly. And yet the header files are designed to be usable from C++, and (to a very limited extent) to take advantage of C++-only features.

Comment: A **very** limited extent.

Comment: So, is there anyone who can answer question 3 that `can all templates be exported with this syntax?`. Usually, templates should only work if implements are also included in the included files.

Comment: @Adam `extern C++` isn't a cheat code to make tempates easier to deal with. (If it was, you would've heard of it before now.) This is a special case, because the templated function doesn't actually need a definition in order to fulfill its purpose.

Answer (score 5):

1. It works by forcing the compiler to use C++ linkage when the surrounding code uses C linkage by default (e.g., you include winnt.h in a C program).
2. Yes, it should be portable.
3. Yes they can.
   There is not much use for "extern "C++"" in C++ programs because the linkage is "C++" anyway. It makes sense to use "extern "C++"" only if there is a good chance that your C++ code will be included into a C code.

Comment: Most likely this `extern "C++"` is in an `extern "C"` block. If not included, the function would attempt to have C linkage.